# Converting cpp_int to binary string

Tags: c++, boost, bit-manipulation, biginteger, data-conversion

How can i convert boost [`cpp_int`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) (>1000 bits) to it's binary representation in string (e.g. `"1011....11001"`) ?

I have tried convert it by `std::bitset`, but it does not work on higher numbers

**Edit - solution:**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746429/c-decimal-to-binary-converting) contains a solution for this question:
Instead of `int` -> `cpp_int`

```
std::string toBinary(boost::multiprecision::cpp_int n)
{
    std::string r;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        r = (n % 2 == 0 ? "0":"1") + r;
        n /= 2;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Welcome ! You question seems interesting.  However, can you show what you've tried and what higher numbers don't work ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/import_export.html