# Is there a pre-defined built-in function to convert a number to its binary format in C++?

Tags: c++

```
Integer.toString(n,8) // decimal to octal

Integer.toString(n,2) // decimal to binary

Integer.toString(n,16) //decimal to Hex
```

We have these functions in java ... do we have such built-in functions in c++

Comment: No, but you can do it easily with [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) using the correct base [manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) (with the exception of binary format).

Comment: There are a *lot* of examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22746429/c-decimal-to-binary-converting

Comment: Converting is very simple , i do agree with it , by using a while lopp we can easily convert it i just wanted to know if there is a pre defined function :)

Comment: There isn't one function that does it. You have to perform a number of operations. There are tricks to make it short (without a loop) in the link as well as what @JoachimPileborg said but other than that...nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an int to a binary string  representation in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890502/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-binary-string-representation-in-c)

Comment: What do you mean "its binary format"? Octal and hex are not binary formats. Do you just mean convert an integer to a string, using a given base?

Comment: @JonathanMee, that only answer one third of the question

Comment: @JonathanWakely Hmm... good comment. I missed that when I first read through. Added an answer as penance.

Comment: @JonathanMee, and it's the only answer that's complete and portable, nice :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks to your comments only. I actually thought `iota` was portable. I've even used it in code that was supposed to be portable. You can imagine my shock when I read [at cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/#portability): "This function is not defined in ANSI-C and is not part of C++, but is supported by some compilers."

Comment: @JonathanMee, it's Windows only AFAIK (and first edition UNIX, but nothing since). Confusion isn't helped by the completely bogus statement in MSDN ["This POSIX function is deprecated. "](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235327.aspx) because it has never been in any POSIX standard!

Comment: @JonathanWakely Wow well done, that is the exact article that I sourced when I wrote my "cross platform" `iota` code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use  `std::bitset`  to convert a number to its binary format.

Use the following code snippet:

```
  std::string binary = std::bitset<8>(n).to_string();
```

Comment: That only answers one third of the question.

Comment: @NilutpalBorgohain It found that this will convert the integer `n` to its binary with 8 binary digits. What if I want to do this at run time and not at compile time?

Answer (score 5):

There is one function available **itoa** present in the `stdlib.h` by which we can convert integer to string. It is not exactly defined in C or C++ but supported by many compilers.

```
char *  itoa ( int value, char * str, int base );
```

**itoa example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int i;
    char buffer [33];
    printf ("Enter a number: ");
    scanf ("%d",&i);
    itoa (i,buffer,10);
    printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
    itoa (i,buffer,16);
    printf ("hexadecimal: %s\n",buffer);
    itoa (i,buffer,2);
    printf ("binary: %s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter a number: 1750
decimal: 1750
hexadecimal: 6d6
binary: 11011010110
```

For more details you can refer [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/)

Comment: `itoa` is not present on most operating systems

Answer (score 3):

If you need a cross platform way to do this [cplusplus.com suggests](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/#portability): `sprintf` is a good option for hex and oct:

```
int Integer = 13;
char toOct[sizeof(int) * (unsigned int)(8.0f / 3.0f) + 2];
char toHex[sizeof(int) * 8 / 4 + 1];
bitset<sizeof(int)> toBin(Integer);

sprintf(toOct, "%o", Integer);
sprintf(toHex, "%x", Integer);

cout << "Binary: " << toBin << "\nOctal: " << toOct << "\nDecimal: " << Integer << "\nHexadecimal: " << toHex << endl;
```

Note that `toOct` and `toHex` are char arrays sized to hold the largest integer in Octal and Hexadecimal strings respectively, so there is no need for dynamic resizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 64;
string binary = bitset<64>(n).to_string();
binary.erase(0, binary.find_first_not_of('0'));
cout << binary << endl;
```

Comment: It's actually pretty good as it trims all the leading bits. It'd be better if we could get it in 1 step though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string binary = bitset<32>(n).to_string();
    cout << binary << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output: 00000000000000000000000000010000